# vert.x JDBCAuth doesn't store User object in RoutingContext

Tags: kotlin, vert.x

I set up JDBCAuth with vert.x, and the authentication works. I get the User object after JDBCAuth.authenticate (adminLoginHandler), but it is null in the RoutingContext at the next HTTP GET query (adminReadHandler).

I checked, the RoutingContext there has session and cookie object.

I add BodyHandler, CookieHandler, SessionHandler.create(LocalSessionStore.create(vertx)), UserSessionHandler.create(adminAuth) before I set the routes.

I use OpenAPI3RouterFactory to set the routing.

I think, I did everything as in the documentation and sample code.
What am I missing?

```
suspend fun createJDBCAuth(vertx : Vertx, name : String) : JDBCAuth
{
    val con = getConnection(vertx, name)
    return JDBCAuth.create(vertx, con)
        .setAuthenticationQuery("SELECT PASSWORD, PASSWORD_SALT FROM \"user\" WHERE USERNAME = ?")
        .setHashStrategy(JDBCHashStrategy.createPBKDF2(vertx))
        .setNonces(json {
            array(45, 385)
        })
}
```

```
adminAuth = createJDBCAuth(vertx, "adminreader")
OpenAPI3RouterFactory.create(vertx, "openapi.yaml")
{ ar ->
    if (ar.succeeded())
    {
        // Spec loaded with success
        var factory = ar.result()

        logger.info("Factory succeed")

        factory.setBodyHandler(BodyHandler.create().setBodyLimit(1024 * 1024))
            .addGlobalHandler(CookieHandler.create())
            .addGlobalHandler(SessionHandler.create(LocalSessionStore.create(vertx)))
            .addGlobalHandler(UserSessionHandler.create(adminAuth))
            .addGlobalHandler(CorsHandler.create("https://localhost:3000")
                .allowCredentials(true)
                .allowedHeader("Content-Type")
                .allowedMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                .allowedMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                .allowedMethod(HttpMethod.OPTIONS)
            )
inputMap.forEach { path ->
    when {
        path.key == "/admin/login" -> factory.addHandlerByOperationId(path.value.operationId, adminLoginHandler)
        path.key.startsWith("/admin/") -> factory.addHandlerByOperationId(path.value.operationId, adminReadHandler)
    }
}
```

Updated function.

```
    private val adminLoginHandler = Handler<RoutingContext>
    { rc ->
        adminAuth.authenticate(rc.bodyAsJson)
        { res ->
            launch {

                var retJson = json { obj() }

                if (res.succeeded()) {

                    var user = res.result()
                    rc.session()?.regenerateId()
                    rc.setUser(user)

                    retJson = retJson.put("succeed", true)

                    if (user.isAuthorizedAwait("createadmin"))
                        retJson = retJson.put("createadmin", true)
                } else {
                    retJson = retJson
                        .put("succeed", false)
                        .put("message", res.cause().message)
                }

                rc.response()
                    .putHeader("content-type", "application/json")
                    .end(retJson.encode())
            }
        }
    }
```

```
private val adminReadHandler = Handler<RoutingContext>
{ rc ->

    if (rc.user() == null)
        rc.response().setStatusCode(403).end()
    else
    {
        val user = rc.user()
        val principal = user.principal()
    }
}
```

Comment: When you manually implement an auth handler, after the authentication you should manually set the user with https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/web/RoutingContext.html#setUser-io.vertx.ext.auth.User-
Add `rc.user = user` in adminLoginHandler

Comment: I changed the adminLoginHandler (updated code in the question), and rc.setUser(user) adds the JDBCUser object to the rc, but still, at the next GET request the rc.user object is null. I see one rc.cookies object with "vertx-web.session" key, but I don't see any cookie in chrome debugger.

Comment: I created a working example mocking the auth provider and removing openapi router factory, can you check it? https://gist.github.com/slinkydeveloper/b1444aa59828c4f3fe657ff67d5d3bad

Comment: The `UserSessionHandler` should do the trick of saving the user into the session and retrieving it. Are you sure the cookie is sent back to the server?

Comment: No, I didn't see any cookie with my implementation.

Comment: After some changes, your gist works for me. The changes: https://gist.github.com/ebadta81/62c1ed5a8fc3d2fbe65afba1d11ff0b5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out, that the problem wasn't at the backend (vertx) side. 
I use the browser fetch api in the frontend code, and I forgot to include the credentials: "include" option.

Francesco: Thank You for your effort. Your gist helped me to trace back the problem piece by piece.

P.s.: although my authn/authz is working now, I still don't see the cookies on the network/cookies panel of the chrome debugger, using fetch api. If I write the url directly to the browser, I see everything.